# Usage of “neigen zu etwas”

Tags: pronoun, verb-usage, relative-clause

To practice the usage of “neigen zu etwas” I constructed the following sentence:

> Der Hund neigt dazu, jeden zu beißen, der in den Garten kommt.

I would like to know if the sentence flows naturally in German or is there a better version for the usage of neigen zu etwas.  For this version of the sentence, have I got the usage of jeden = anyone (accusative) and der = who „nominative“ correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly correct, both in terms of grammar and in terms of style. Note however, that *neigen zu* is a bit elevated style. You would rather not use it in everyday oral communication. You can perfectly well use it in a parliamentary speech or some official report or printed piece of text or so.

Here are more sample sentences with "neigen zu":

> Im Norden neigt das Wetter dazu, wechselhaft zu sein.
>
> Die CDU neigt dazu, Werte wie Heimat und Tradition zu betonen.
>
> Der Kirschbaum hier neigt dazu, bei Trockenheit seine Blätter fallen zu lassen.

For oral everyday communication you would usually tend to use other words.

> Der Kirschbaum hier lässt bei Trockenheit gerne mal die Blätter fallen.
>
> Im Norden ist das Wetter sehr wechselhaft.
>
> Die CDU tendiert dazu, Werte wie Heimat und Tradition zu betonen.
>
> Die CDU betont oft Werte wie Heimat und Tradition.

Attention with

> Das Öl im Tank neigt sich dem Ende zu.

This sentence is also correct, but it uses an expression "sich dem Ende zu neigen" which is something different.

Comment: Ich neige dazu, diese Konstruktion andauernd zu benutzen.  –– So "gehoben" ist *neigen zu* nun nicht, aber ich weiss auch nicht, ob "a bit" hier britisch oder amerikanisch gemeint ist. –– Der Hund tendiert…, präferiert…,  Vielleicht im Vergleich zu "Der Hund beisst gern/gewöhnlich/immer jeden…" Vgl [auch österreichische Verwendung](https://www.laut.de/Neigungsgruppe-Sex,-Gewalt-und-gute-Laune)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm ... einerseits gebe ich Christan G. Recht, und andererseits auch nicht. Sowohl mehrere seiner Sätze als auch dein Satz liegen irgendwo zwischen zweifelhaft und unsinnig/sinnlos.

'zu etwas neigen' bezeichnet eher einen Charakterzug eines Menschen oder einer Körperschaft (siehe das CDU-Beispiel). Ob das Wetter oder ein Kirschbaum tatsächlich einen Charakter haben? Ich denke eher nicht. Und ein Hund? Hundenarren werden jetzt sofort im Brustton der Überzeugung "Aber natürlich!" rufen. ich hätte da so meine Zweifel.

Aber abgesehen davon: Entweder der Hund **neigt dazu, Leute** zu beißen - dann tut er das häufig, aber eben nicht immer - , oder er **beißt jeden**, der in den Garten kommt - dann neigt er nicht.  Sagt mir die Logik.